# Remove underlining caused by abbr tag

Tags: html, css, abbr

I use the `<abbr>` tag to show the full content of some trimmed words with the CSS property `text-overflow: ellipsis` .

When using `<abbr>` these words get a dotted underline and on hover cursor changes to one with a question mark.

I did manage to change it using this. But, I'm not sure this is the best way, is there anything wrong with this approach?

```
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  cursor: default !important;
}
```

Comment: Have yout tried `text-decoration: none;` ?

Comment: IMO problem is you're using `<abbr>` with **wrong semantic**. It's for **abbreviations**, not for truncated text. It's like you want to change `<h1>` because you're using that tag for footnotes...

Comment: I believe that this is better fitted for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If it's too old to be migrated, I believe it should be closed as off topic. Stack Overflow is Question Answer, not Question Advice.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Starting with v40 Firefox [switched](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/40/Site_Compatibility#CSS) to using text-decoration to provide the underline and chromium will be [doing it that way too](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=480213). So you should update your code to include that if you need to support those browsers:

```
abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  cursor: inherit !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: `cursor: inherit` would be a better option in case the `abbr` is within an `a` tag or some other context where the cursor should not be the default. I'll go ahead and edit your answer.

Comment: important isn't necessary, and screws you over if you need to add your own proper border later.

Comment: Good grief, this baffled me for at least an hour. It's `border-bottom` AND `text-decoration`.

Answer (score 12):

It sets a border and `text-decoration`. Remove that with:

```
border: none;
text-decoration: none;
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbggLevn/)

Comment: It seems it doesn't work (FF 40 here), you need to add text-decoration: none for it to work

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
abbr[title] {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

This uses [styling abbreviations.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Styling_Abbreviations_and_Acronyms)

Answer (score 0):

```
abbr[title] {cursor: default !important;}
```

Comment: the answer is already mention below, you just re-writing it again.

Comment: @Joseph A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Answer (score 0):

Remove that with `abbr[title] {text-decoration: none !important;}`